# add layer values to legend

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

i have created a legend.

```
var legend = new Legend({
      map: map,
      layerInfos: [
        {
          layer: S_layer,
          title: "Factors"
        }

      ]
    }, "legendDiv"); 
   legend.startup();
```

now i want to add another attribute of the same layer into the legend. 
i have seen examples of adding another layer to the legend . but could not find any example of how to add attributes of same layer to the legend. can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?